# ~/Pictures directory missing

Tags: 16.04, command-line, home-directory

The `Pictures` directory is missing in the sidebar of the file manager and when I use terminal to do `cd ~/Pictures` it shows `/home/sm/Pictures: No such file or directory`.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and my `Pictures` directory was existing last week.

Here's how the file manager's side bar looks:

[image: list of folders/directories in sidebar: Recent, Home, Desktop, Downloads, Music, Videos, Trash, Network, Computer, Myfile, win, Connect to...]

Comment: Can you please do `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and tell us what does it say ? Is `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` defined there or not ? Have you installed any new software or ran any commands such as `rm` that could operate on `~/Pictures` ?

Comment: thanks .
after run cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs it shows to me also XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
 and i don't think thar run rm for ~/Pictures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"` should be `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"`, so open that  `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file in text editor, and correct the issue. After logging out and logging back in ( if simply logging in/out doesn't work , try reboot), new `~/Pictures` folder should be created and show up in file manager.

As for the old one, it's a mystery where it may have disappeared and probably whatever files you had there are gone with it.

Comment: By gedit cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs i opened this and change XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"  to  XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures" But after logout did not change .
and when run cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs  it shows XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
and Pictures dir missing .

Comment: OK, try this instead in terminal : `sed -ir  's;(XDG_PICTURES_DIR=.*)\";\1Pictures\";g' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` That's one  in `\1`, don't confuse it with letter l ! Then log out and log in. If that doesn't work, you've more serious problem where your `user-dirs.dirs` file is being over written all the time

Comment: I Copied that in terminal and  it shows 
`sed: -e expression #1, char 40: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`

Comment: @cooder sorry, my bad, you need to separate `-i` and `-r` , it should be `sed -i -r` , separately

Comment: Yes ... thanks a lot @sergiy . my problem fixed .
What was the problem ? !

Comment: That file, `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`  lists settings for all standard user directories,. File manager reads that. If  one of directories is unset - file manager will ignore it.  While I don't know why your `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` got unset, I can only guess that some other program you installed recently  or something else has edited this setting

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a multi-step step process:

1. Open a terminal window in the `Home` directory
2. In the terminal window create the new Pictures folder:

   ```
   mkdir Pictures
   ```
3. Open `user-dirs.dirs` in `~/.config`
4. Edit `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"` to `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"`
5. Save and close `user-dirs.dirs` in `~/.config`
6. In the terminal window, execute `xdg-user-dirs-update` to make certain it does not change anything.
7. Reopen `user-dirs.dirs` to make certain it did not change `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"` back to `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"`